# Strange behaviour of bit shift

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Why the two **printf** statements are outputting different values?

```
int main()
{
    int n=10;

    printf("%d\n",(n&0xAAAAAAAA)>>1 + n&0x55555555  ); //prints 0

    printf("%d\n", n&0x55555555 + (n&0xAAAAAAAA)>>1 ); //prints 10

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/B33YB

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because of the [operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence).

`+` is executed earlier than `>>`.

When you change

`(n&0xAAAAAAAA)>>1 + n&0x55555555)`

to

`n&0x55555555 + (n&0xAAAAAAAA)>>1)`

you are actually changing the order in which the operations are executed.

`(n&0xAAAAAAAA)>>1 + n&0x55555555` can be rewritten as `(n&0xAAAAAAAA)>>(1 + n&0x55555555)` which is different compared to `((n&0xAAAAAAAA)>>1) + n&0x55555555` (which is what the second line states)

The same goes for the `+` and the `&` operator.

So to make the output their outputs similar you need additional parenthesis:

```
int main()
{
    int n=10;

    printf("%d\n",((n&0xAAAAAAAA)>>1) + (n&0x55555555) ); // prints 5
    printf("%d\n",(n&0x55555555) + ((n&0xAAAAAAAA)>>1) ); // prints 5

    return 0;
}
```

See http://ideone.com/d3mHT

Comment: If the second line states: ((n&0xAAAAAAAA)>>1) + n&0x55555555, then it should output 5 in place of 10. But, it's showing 10.

Comment: @0A0D I am finished writing my answer (I think), I noticed we were changing each others modifications... (well I was changing yours) Thank you help helping out, it was not deliberate.

Comment: @algogeek because the `+` operation has precedence over the `&` you need more parenthesis.

Comment: @Veger: No problem, I noticed that too.. I was trying to help you out as much as possible :)